# Jboss AS 7 and class loading

Tags: jboss, resteasy

I am using JBOSS AS 7.0.2 Final,  and was trying to upgrade the version of RESTEASY that comes with 7.0.2 RESTEASY 2.2.1.GA to a newer version such as 2.3.4.Final.   I followed the directions as indicated in patching provided by JBOSS, and when I did that, at application server startup it throws the error of being unable to parse the module.xml file.

I attempted the same procedure on 7.1.1 Final and it works fine.

First Question is, anyone know how to update RESTEASY in 7.0.2  (My other servers are all using this so I really like not to have to reset my other servers and replace with newer version of JBOSS)

I was hoping to upgrade RESTEASY, with hopes that this error may have been resolved in newer version

I have also tried by adjusting my POM to use version 2.3.4.Final and tried every scope, but it always would fail to use the newer jars and stick with JBOSS supplied jar.

> 15:14:09,947 SEVERE [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] (http--127.0.0.1-8443-6) Failed executing POST /countermeasure/customQueryLite: org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.util.ArrayList of media type
>   : application/xml
>
> > at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponse.writeTo(ServerResponse.java:216) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]

It works fine for json, and text, and singular xml objects, but not list objects for xml.

Any answers in regards to these issues with resteasy and jboss would be helpful.

Comment: For a hack right now, this works to get the right MessageBody Writer
List<Pojo> pojos = pojoDAO.search(query);
GenericEntity<List<Pojo>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<Pojo>>(pojos) {};